# Login Integration between New MultiSite WP and existing site

Tags: wordpress

I have an existing site. (sodabrasil.com)

I have a new WP site, which was a subdomain of that site. (paskin.sodabrasil.com). I have changed it as much as I could to be sodabrasil.com/paskin

They both have logins.

I am trying to integrate both of them in a way that when a person logins in one site, the user is also logged in in the other site. It has to work in either direction.

I have done that in the past, and it worked with single site.

Now the current WP site is multisite & originally a subdomain and it has been a challange.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deactivating all plugins and put blog id etc, where you are including wp-blog-header.php.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, But it still redirecting to subdomain where I installed wordpress multisite you can visit sodabrasil.com